# what does the size of a tree means in weighted union find algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

I saw that in [union find](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/) it says:

> Weighted quick-union. Rather than arbitrarily connecting the second tree to the first for union() in the quick-union algorithm, we keep track of the size of each tree and always connect the smaller tree to the larger.

what is defined as the `size` of each tree? what is the size?

Comment: Number of elements in the tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in the later part of the page.

> Definitions. The size of a tree is its number of nodes